# Powershell Parameters: How to read order of user input

Tags: powershell, parameters

I am trying to determine the order in which the user enters parameters. So, using the following example:

```
function RepeatParamOrder {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [bool]$param1=$false,
        [bool]$param2=$false,
        [bool]$param3=$false
    )

    Write-Output <order user entered params>
}
```

If the user were to enter the following:

```
C:\>RepeatParamOrder -param3 true -param1 true
```

I would ideally like to capture the following order in some delimited format: `(param3,param1)`

The reason order is important is there are many, many parameters the user can enter and the order they enter parameters is the order a RETURN array will output values associated with those parameters. So, in this example, a 2-D array of arrays with data associated with `(param3,param1)` is returned and `param2` is ignored since the user does not desire that information.

I have been searching well over an hour for a solution that would allow for the script to read the order parameters as entered but have had no luck finding a solution. I also searched for how to simply read the entire line `C:\>RepeatParamOrder -param3 true -param1 true` so that I could create a loop to parse out the information. And, while it seems basic that there should be a command that simply returns the text of the line I cannot find that solution either. I have looked through `Get-Content` and `Read-Host` but they do not seem to provide a solution (i.e. once the user enters parameter  values, the function/script will do everything else without additional user input being required - such as providing order beyond the order the named parameters are already entered).

There must be an obvious solution but I am either searching the wrong keywords or misinterpreting a solution (e.g. maybe `Read-Host` is the solution but I am not grasping it correctly to extract information from the original user parameter input).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the properties of [$MyInvocation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#myinvocation). Try the following:

```
function RepeatParamOrder {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [bool]$param1=$false,
        [bool]$param2=$false,
        [bool]$param3=$false
    )

    Write-Output $MyInvocation.Line
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I can work with this.

Comment: You're welcome. Another option may be the `$PSBoundParameters` automatic variable, but I'm not sure there's any guarantee that order is preserved.